# Cohomology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have some questions.

1) I tried to compute the cohomology group of $S^3$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ but I don't know if my result
$$
H^k(S^3,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = \begin{cases}
  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},  & \text{if }k=0,3\\
  0, &\text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
is correct. How can I check it for myself?

2) If I have a wedgesum $X \vee Y$ of topological spaces $X$ and $Y$.  I read that relative cohomology of this wedgesum coincide with the direct sum of cohomology group of $X$ and $Y$.  In absolute case that isn't true in general, but in which situations is$H^*(X \vee  Y)\cong H^*(X)\oplus H^*(Y)$ in absolute case? $H^*(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2 \vee S^3, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^3, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$

Edit: 3) My goal is to prove that $ \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2 \vee S^3$ and $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^3$ are not homotopy equivalent. Therefore I need $H^*(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2 \vee S^3, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^*(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^3, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ to compute the cohomology rings. 
$H^k(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^3,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = \begin{cases}
  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},  & \text{if }k=0,1,2,3\\
  0, &\text{else}
\end{cases}$

Maybe, it is a example where $H^*(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2 \vee S^3, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^*(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^3, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. But I don't know how to compute the cohomology of this wedge sum. 
I would appreciate any help from here.

Regards

Comment: Your $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ calculations are correct.

Comment: To anti-echo Sammy's comment, your $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ calculations are incorrect, or maybe it's a typo! Then non-zero cohomology is in degrees $0$ and $3$.

Comment: oh thank's, it is a typo, I correct that. @all thank you!

Comment: It's good to edit your question to fix typos, but don't reintroduce spelling mistakes others corrected! The correct spelling of **wedge sum** contains a space, so does **cohomology group**, **cohomology ring** and **homotopy equivalence**.

Comment: sorry, I changed that.

Comment: Well, you corrected some of it. Also, you are stating results about the **reduced cohomology** of a space, not of relative cohomology, which is the cohomology of a pair $A\subset X$.

Answer (score 1):

Your sphere cohomology is correct. I'm not sure what you mean by verifying it. You can verify it by looking in any textbook or wikipedia article or checking your computation (you know how to compute the result, right?).

The cohomology of the wedgesum should be pretty obvious: wedge sum differs from disjoint union only in degree $0$ by gluing the base-points together. Consequently, the homologies of $X \vee Y$ and $X \coprod Y$ coincide except in the degree zero. Now as $H^0(X)$ measures number of connected components of $X$, it's also obvious that $H^0(X \vee Y)$ will be one less than $H^0(X \coprod Y)$ since we glue two components (those containing basepoints) together.

The above paragraph should also answer your question about your particular wedge sum. In general $H^*(X)$ and $H^*(X \vee Y)$ coincide if only if $Y$ has homotopy type of a point.

Comment: Your last comment is incorrect. What if $X$ and $Y$ are both equal to an infinite wedge of any non-contractible space?

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for pointing this out. I was implicitly assuming finite generation.